# How to fetch a list of rows and foreach in it in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

I have a table named `Click` in sql database. This table stores clicks of everything. This table has a field named `EntityTypeId` that says this row is for which entity. I want to fetch a special type of clicks and store them in another table. So I should select them from `Click` table and insert them in `PriceClick` table.

Here is the `Click` table records:

```
ClickId  |  EntityTypeId
------------------------
   1             1
   2             2
   3             2
   4             3
```

Here is the required rows for `Click` table and `PriceClick` table:

`Price`:

```
ClickId  |  EntityTypeId
------------------------
   1             1
   4             3
```

`PriceClick`:

```
ClickId  |  EntityTypeId
------------------------
   2             2
   3             2
```

How to do this?

Comment: The second Table is 'Click' table or 'Price' table?

Comment: The first table is Click table and the second is PriceClick table.

Comment: What is the 'EntityTypeId' for Price?

Comment: The price table stores clicks of multiple entities. The EntityTypeId shows that each row is for which entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INSERT INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO PriceClick(ClickId, EntityTypeId)
SELECT ClickId, EntityTypeId
FROM Click
WHERE EntityTypeId = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SELECT INTO` if you don't have the DestinationTable or Use `INSERT INTO` as the other answer mentioned (@wewesthemenace) if you already created your DestinationTable

```
SELECT *
INTO DestinationTable
FROM SourceTable
WHERE ....
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a bulk insert from one table to another and you have similar table structure, you do not need to use any `foreach` or other loops.

There is a simple way to achieve this -

```
CREATE TABLE Click  (ClickId bigint, EntityTypeId bigint)

INSERT INTO Click VALUES (1,1)
INSERT INTO Click VALUES (2,2)
INSERT INTO Click VALUES (3,2)
INSERT INTO Click VALUES (4,3)

CREATE TABLE PriceClick (ClickId bigint, EntityTypeId bigint)

INSERT INTO PriceClick (ClickId,EntityTypeId)
SELECT ClickId,EntityTypeId 
FROM Click WHERE ClickId = 2 

CREATE TABLE Price (ClickId bigint, EntityTypeId bigint)
INSERT INTO Price (ClickId,EntityTypeId)
SELECT ClickId,EntityTypeId 
FROM Click WHERE ClickId <> 2
```

**Please note** you should have same Datatype definition in main table